# How to make a strategy only trade high volume days on tradingview?

Tags: pine-script, volume, strategy-pattern

I'm trying to make it so my strategy will only trade on high volume days, but I am rather stuck, and am struggling to use the input.timeframe that is suggested in the pine script references. I feel it's just a silly mistake I am making.

```
timeframe = input('D', "Resolution", options=['D', 'W', 
'M'])
highvolume = timeframe and volume > 10 * volume[1] and volume > 
100000
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
//@version=5
indicator('Test', overlay=true)

tf = input.timeframe('D', "Resolution", options=['D', 'W', 'M'])

vol = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, volume)
highvolume = vol > 10 * vol[1] and vol > 100000

bgcolor(highvolume ? color.green : na)
```